# Using the simpletest automator in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, simpletest

I've been trying to learn how to use simpletest, and I found the simpletest automator.  I was able to install it and run it, but where is the file with the results of the 'macro' saved?  I haven't been able to find it.

Also, is there a quick way to duplicate a drupal install in simpletest?  I know it starts from a clean install, but I don't want to have to go through and figure out what all is enabled and who has what permissions at the start of the test.  Is there a script that can figure out the settings of the current drupal install?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a script that can figure out the settings of the current drupal install?

The short answer is no.

Essentially simpletest should be used as a unit test framework. Where all of the data that is needed is set up at the beginning of the test and it is not reliant on system setting or a particular user having a permission. It does this quite well, and can test core functionality and individual modules easily. If you are testing an indavidual module you have written using simpletest is, well, simple.

Unfortunately most websites use a number of modules and are configured to work together in a very specific way. Simpletest doesn't cope with this very well.

There are ways to get around this:

One option is to write a setup script in php which will work as a big setup script for your test. This can create users, set settings and permissions. This can be dificult to write and maintain and can cause the tests to take a long time to run.

Another option is for the site testing (which is different from unit testing) to be done in a tool other than simpletest. I have had some success with [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). The downside to this is that you need to find a way have clean data. Which can be tricky, copying a database works but doesn't scale.

Answer (score 0):

I've been pointed to this blog post as an answer to the question: http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/forcing-simpletest-use-live-database

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [site deployment module](http://dcycleproject.org/blog/44/what-site-deployment-module) and enable only that at the very beginning of your test (in your `SetUp()` function).